# Pg-promise vs sequelize, To handle millions of sql queries

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, pg-promise

Module [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) provides method [sequence](http://vitaly-t.github.io/spex/global.html#sequence) to execute infinite sequences, suitable for massive transactions, like bulk inserts, with way over 1,000 records. And it supports [query streams](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Learn-by-Example#from-database) for high-performance, read-only queries.

**Does Sequelize offer anything similar to those things?**

Sorry for asking such basic things, but I am new and don't have any idea about these two.

Thanks for your response and suggestions.

Comment: Check the source code for one, then the documentation and the source code for the other.

Comment: To my knowledge, No, sequelize doesn't support any of those.

Answer (score 2):

This answer will probably anger some of the [Sequelize](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize) fans, but in the name of truth...

---

What you're referring to within [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) is fully documented in [Data Imports](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Data-Imports).

And no, [Sequelize](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize) doesn't have anything like that.

And in addition, [Sequelize](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize) is known to be plagued by performance issues, like this one: [Transactions extremely slow when inserting 1000s of records](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/2995), ones that are very bad and very old at the same time.

Comment: i agree, i started with sequelize but quickly moved to a lower level library, sequelize should be used only after clearly establishing the nature of queries in your application, how many inserts, how big of inserts etc are needed